# show differences in JSON objects, preferably as a treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I currently have two json objects, containing configuration information, being loaded by javascript in a webpage.

These json objects are being displayed in two treeviews side by side. I'm currently using jqtree for this.

I need to be able to highlight the differences between the two json objects similar to the code comparison tools you get within notepad++ and other dev environments.

I would rather stick with treeviews of some description if possible but it's not the most important part of this.  If anyone can suggest a package which can do this that would be great but any general suggestions would be useful.

Comment: This question is arguably just a shopping question unless you show that you've thought about rolling it yourself or tried something.

Comment: You can use `$.each()` to "walk" the properties of each object and compare their values... I usually do `Object.keys(o).forEach()` to do that, but the jQuery method works in IE8, unlike my technique.

Comment: Could you post a demo (jsFiddle.net) of your object trees? I don't know how the generated DOM structure looks like...

Comment: This is what you need. https://github.com/samsonjs/json-diff

Comment: Thanks everyone, Joshua has given me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

github.com/samsonjs/json-diff is the perfect solution, thanks to JoshuaBoshi for posting.